# Git for A Web Directory With Branches

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up a web server's version control systsem using git, but I'm thoroughly confused.

So I want there to be 2 branches: experimental, and release.

I wrote hooks to move the files to the web directory when a release is merged with experimental. However, I really don't know how to set up the repository on the server, and then locally.

Do I need a bare repository on the server (I'm not 100% sure what that is)?
How do I create the branches, switch to them, and then send commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a normal repo on the server.

If you have access to the server, what you can do is to do a copy of your local repo into your server. Once done, your server and local repo are in sync. Then you can use git remote add command to add your server as your local's remote, so that each time you push, it will go into the server.

example adding a remote called origin:
git remote add origin git@domain.com/project.git

Next time you have updates on your local repo, you can just update the server by using the command `git push origin master`

To make branch, it's easy:

```
git branch newbranch
```

To change into this branch:

```
git checkout newbranch
```

To list all branch:

```
git branch -a
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good start. I'll need to read up on git more!